# Label loading slower than all other UI Views after segue

Tags: ios, uilabel, segue

I initiate a segue using the performSegueWithIdentifier function, and I have the segue declared on the storyboard as a regular push. It might also be helpful to know that every element on the screen is aligned relative to the horizontal center of the screen and the space from top or space from bottom or vertical center.

When the segue occurs, all of the buttons appear on the app almost immediately. Then, about 30 seconds later, the label appears.

I'm using swift with the newest version of xCode, and I'm testing on an iPhone 6 simulator.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

---- Update ----
To give you some more information, the view is a screen similar to the lock screen after swiping to unlock your iPhone. It has 12 buttons for each numerical key, and back and clear. 4 Spaces to show input. 4 hidden '*' buttons that appear on top of each space when you click a number.

All of it was laid out in the gui, so I'm sure the xml looks awful (filled with several 'magic numbers'), but I'll post it here:

http://pastebin.com/YAWRX9c4

---- Update 2 ----

It looks like this behavior ONLY happens if I segue to the scene. If I set the scene to be the main scene, everything loads at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible to share some relevant code? Maybe any async network calls on the pushed controller?

Comment: There are no network calls in the app. I'll update the question with some relevant information

Comment: The XML is not very helpful in resolving your problem (and the layout constraints are not relevant either). Show the code you have in the controller you're segueing to. 
It might also be useful to see the method where you invoke the segue in the previous controller.

Comment: The project is at https://github.com/wortman/stroll_safe_ios.  It's hackathon code, and we were new to IOS coding, so it's pretty sloppy. The segue call is in the main ViewController.swift. The controller it segues to is LockdownControllerViewController.swift (yes, I plan to change that name). Thanks!

Comment: I should also specify that both the Stroll Safe label and the Circle Progress Bar do not load until 30 seconds after the segue from ViewController.swift to LockdownControllerViewController in the version on github

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're executing your performSegue call on a background thread -- doing any UI manipulation on a background thread is almost always the reason for this kind of long delay if you're not doing network calls. Wrap that call in a dispatch_async block,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("lockdownSegue", sender: nil)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly! So do UI click events happen in background threads?

Comment: @Noah, no they don't; all UI events are on the main thread. Your code had the performSegue method within a dispatch_async block, that was on the global queue you had further up in the enterReleaseState()  function. That was the problem.